# Where are the unlocked characters in Sonic & All-Stars Racing Transformed?

Tags: sonic-all-stars-racing-transformed

I have been playing *Sonic & All-Stars Racing Transformed* and I have unlocked many different characters throughout career mode but I can't seem to find them in character selection. I only have the default characters.

I have unlocked them and it does say "You have unlocked xxxxx" when unlocking a character. How do I actually play them though? Am I able to play them in career? I can't even play them in online mode, there simply not there. I am playing on computer, if it makes a difference.

Comment: What platform is this on?

Comment: PC. Completely forgot to mention that sorry...

Comment: I play it via Steam and each character unlock made it available in all game modes.  Did you actually click the character to unlock them?